# NHibernate: inserting additional calculated column

Tags: nhibernate

What would be your approach with NHibernate to do the following:
When `Comment` is inserted into DB, and its property `Text` is inserted into column `Text` (due to a mapping), insert into column `TextHash` a hash of this property value.

It seems trivial if I map `TextHash`, but how should I do this without mapping it?
I do not need it in the domain model, its a DB-level optimization (I would use computed HashBytes if not for the length limit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some similar questions, such as this one:
[Unmapped Columns in NHibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579885/unmapped-columns-in-nhibernate)

However, `IInterceptor` seems like an overkill for a change in a single entity insert. And `EventListeners` are less than perfectly documented and also somewhat too complex for a single column.

So I have decided on the solution that I see both as most reusable and most local:

```
  <property name="Text" type="StringWithMD5HashUserType">
    <column name="Text" length="20000" not-null="true" />
    <column name="TextHash" length="32" not-null="true" />
  </property>
```

Where `StringWithMD5HashUserType` is `ICompositeUserType` that reads `Text` from first column, but writes both `Text` and its `Hash` (I do not add the code of `StringWithMD5HashUserType` because it is way too long, but essentially very simple).

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't want to use the property, declare it private and calculate it when you set the text property. It's not exactly "without mapping it", but you won't see it when you're using the class (disclaimer: advice based on Hibernate, as opposed to NHibernate).

Other than that, you could always write a trigger, although I'd personally much rather add a private field and be done with it.

Comment: I know I can use private one, but it is not exactly persistence ignorant. So that's kind of goes against NH strengths as I see them.

Comment: I'm afraid I fail to see the downside of declaring a private field. Semantically, declaring it that way, you basically _are_ saying it's a " local implementation detail", it's "not to be used from outside of the entity", and the rest of the application remains blissfully ignorant of the calculated field. You need to place the hashing logic _somewhere_, and I can only think of two places: the model and the database. Anyway, feel free to disregard. :)

Comment: I see the third location, examples of which are IUserType or IInterceptor and which does not tie hashing algorithm directly to the entity. I just do not see what extensibility point of NHibernate applies to my use case.

Comment: Seems like I'm overgeneralising when assuming hibernate and nhibernate are twin implementation. I'm interested in hearing what sort of conclusion the question will come to.

Comment: I answered with approach that I ended up using.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion:
As far as I know you can't access a column in your DB using NHibernate if it there no mapping defined for it.
To prevent other parts of your application to see this field of your class you can define its access as field in your mapping so that it can be private an no one knows that it exists but NHibernate:
In your class:

```
private string _textHash
```

In your mapping:

```
<property name='_textHash' column='TextHash' access='field' />
```

Comment: Well, this is practically the same thing Tomislav suggests. It has same problems: ties entity to hashing algorithm, which really an implementation detail, ties entity to the DB structure.  


Also, a private field no one uses has a large probability of being removed by Resharper-wielding developers.